# PATH="/custom/dir:$PATH" prepending instead of appending - Conda vs Pyenv

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, zsh, pyenv

I have a Mac (latest software update) with Pyenv and Anaconda. I manage packages with Homebrew and have installed Python 3 with it. When I `echo $PATH` I get the following:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:
\ /usr/local/bin:
\ /usr/bin:
\ /bin:
\ /usr/local/sbin:
\ /usr/sbin:
\ /sbin:
\ /Library/TeX/texbin:
\ /Users/luca/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-2020.02/condabin:
\ /Users/luca/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/bin:
\ /Users/luca/.pyenv/bin
```

1. I do not know what sets up `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin`: this directory is non-existent on my Mac. I had previously installed Python without Homebrew that is [why the directory was created](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/27146). I did remove that, but there is still something that exports that line in `$PATH`, but I cannot find it! Does someone have a guess? I did try and `grep -r /*` it, but that is too much of a search for my laptop to finish.
2. I set up in my `.zshenv` the code for initialising `pyenv` and `conda`. Of course, I did write `PATH="/dir/to/conda/bin:$PATH"` and the same for `pyenv` (see code below). I do not understand why, but they end up at the *end* of `$PATH`. Does someone know why? Is it because of `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` being evaluated before `conda`?

```
# >>> pyenv initialize
export PYENV_SHELL=$SHELL
export PATH="/Users/luca/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/Users/luca/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/bin:$PATH" #export Python 3.8 bin directory
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
    eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
# <<< pyenv initialize <<<

# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/luca/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-2020.02/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/luca/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-2020.02/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/luca/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-2020.02/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/luca/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-2020.02/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

**In macOS, if you place any code that modifies `$PATH` on macOS inside `.zshenv`, it will be overridden. You should put it in `.zshrc` or somewhere else which is then sourced by your `.zshrc`.**

## Complete explanation

As answered on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/720669/402599), when zsh is sourced, files are read in the following order:

`etc/zshenv/` -> `$ZDOTDIR/.zshenv/` -> `etc/zprofile/` -> `$ZDOTDIR/.zprofile/` -> `etc/zshrc/` -> `$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc/` -> `etc/zlogin/` -> `$ZDOTDIR/.zlogin/`

In macOS's `/etc/zprofile`, a script is sourced that overrides the $PATH according to the contents of these files:

```
/etc/paths
/etc/paths.d
/etc/manpaths
/etc/manpaths.d
```

So you should put not put any line that changes `$PATH` in your `$ZDOTDIR/.zshenv`, but rather in any file sourced after that (e.g. `$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc`). **Do *not* edit files in `/etc/`!**

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem, and I could not find any other source on why the conda environment gets appended instead of prepended. I have added the following code to my .bash_profile (after conda initialisation) which flips the order of all path location. This is definitely a terrible practice, but it might be a quick fix for someone who is stuck on the same problem.

```
locations=($(echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n"))
path=""

for (( idx=${#locations[@]}-2 ; idx>=0 ; idx-- )) ; do
    # Skip the last path location since this would put the general /Users/XXX/opt/anaconda3/condabin first
    # To not do this change the -2 to -1
    path="${path}:${locations[$idx]}"
done

path="${path:1}"
PATH=$path
export $PATH
```

As noted in the comment, I do not add the location "/Users/XXX/opt/anaconda3/condabin", since it would mess up my environment location, which is located second to last. Please examine your own path variable and decide accordingly.

EDIT: If anyone has a better solution, please let me know!

Comment: I finally realised the solution to this: will add an answer accordingly, however the link to the complete and original answer is [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/720669/402599)